# "If you kinda want something, you kinda get the results" auf Deutsch

Tags: english-to-german, idiomaticity

"If you kinda want something, then you will kinda get the results you want."

Ich habe einige Ideen, zum Beispiel:

- Wenn du es nur halbherzig willst, dann erzielst du auch nur halbherzige Ergebnisse.
- Wenn du etwas irgendwie möchtest, dann wird es dir auch nur irgendwie gelingen.
- Wenn du Etwas ein wenig möchtest, bekommst du auch nur ein wenig Etwas.
- Wenn du etwas irgendwie möchtest, dann erhältst du auch bloß irgendwie Ergebnisse.
- Wenn du - wie auch immer - etwas möchtest, dann wirst du - wie auch immer - die Ergebnisse bekommen, die du möchtest.
- Wenn du etwas willst, wirst du auch das Ergebnisse erzielen, welches du dir wünschst.

Aber ich bin mir nicht sicher, weil ich kein Muttersprachler bin.

Comment: Der Titlel Deiner Frage ist nicht spezifisch genug für zukünftig hilfreiche Ergebnisse einer Suche. Bitte ändere dies!

Answer (score 2):

*If you kinda want something, then you will kinda get the results you want.*

> Wenn du etwas **nur** irgendwie möchtest, dann wird es dir auch nur irgendwie gelingen.
>
> Wenn du etwas **bloß** irgendwie möchtest, dann erhältst du auch bloß **irgendwelche** Ergebnisse.

Diese Sätze klingen natürlich und transportieren auch die Zweideutigkeit des englischen Satzes am besten.

> Wenn du es nur halbherzig willst, dann erzielst du auch nur halbherzige Ergebnisse.

Dieser Satz klingt eindeutiger und mehr nach Ratgeber als natürlich.

> Wenn du Etwas **nur** ein wenig möchtest, bekommst du auch nur ein wenig **davon**.

Dieser Satz klingt schon arg gekünstelt. Die anderen Sätze sind sehr umständlich und unverständlich.

Comment: Das "nur" oder "bloß" in der Übersetzung transportieren die Zweideutigkeit gerade nicht. Im Englischen steht nichts Derartiges (only, just).

Answer (score 1):

Für meine Ohren klingt dein erstes Beispiel sehr gut. Ich würde nur *es* durch *etwas* ersetzen.

> Wenn du etwas nur halbherzig willst, erzielst du auch nur halbherzige Ergebnisse.

Answer (score 0):

Mein Vorschlag ist eine freiere Übersetzung:

> So wie Du Dich für ein Ziel einsetzt, wird auch das Ergebnis ausfallen.

Etwas näher am Original:

> Wenn Du etwas so lala möchtest, wirst Du es auch so lala bekommen.

Answer (score 0):

Es ist nicht ganz einfach, im Deutschen den lakonischen Ton zu treffen. Vielleicht

> Wenn du was *so ein bisschen* willst, kriegst du *so ein bisschen* was du willst.

Ein richtig gutes Äquivalent zu "kinda" in "I kinda want this." fällt mir nicht ein.

Von deinen Vorschlägen gefällt mir am besten:

> Wenn du etwas irgendwie möchtest, dann erhältst du auch bloß irgendwie Ergebnisse.

Answer (score 0):

Hier bietet es sich an, *kinda* mit *quasi* zu übersetzen, um ähnlich unspezifisch wie im Orginal zu bleben:

> Wenn du etwas quasi willst, wirst du es auch nur quasi bekommen.

Comment: Hört sich nicht gut an ...

Comment: @PaulFrost genau wie das englische Original...